# When restarting after closing laptop, Ubuntu 12.04 will not boot / cannot find operating software

Tags: boot, system-installation

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit(USB) on my Aspire One with Windows Vista and it seemed to work just fine up until I closed my laptop so it could sleep.

When I attempted to work on my laptop again, a fuzzy screen appeared and wouldn't return me to Ubuntu.

I restarted it and it told me it couldn't find any operating software.

Comment: try boot-repair.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally load up Ubuntu via a Live USB and use Boot Repair as mentioned. There's a good tutorial located here:

http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Answer (score 0):

After booting into a live CD/USB you can use [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to solve the issue.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

Now launch boot repair from either :

1. the Dash (the Ubuntu logo at the top-left of the screen)
2. or System->Administration->Boot-Repair menu (Ubuntu 10.04 only)
3. or by typing 'boot-repair' in a terminal

Then click the "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, note the URL (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a paper, then reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs.